# SQL Server 2014 - listening SQL Server Agent Job vs stored procedure "waitfor delay" - every second - options? possible overhead concerns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm looking to create some kind of listening process for when an item gets added to a table.

It could be a SQL Agent job, scheduled to run every second.

It could be a stored procedure with a `waitfor` delay of 1 second.

I don't want to use Service broker: too complex (cross DBs / certificates, etc).

1. Which of job / Delay is preferred?
2. Any overheads / performance?
3. If I want to make it every 0.1 seconds, are there any overheads?
4. Any other recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: just curious.. what do you want to happen when a record is inserted/? because you could use a trigger on INSERT to call some kind of bat file or something.

Comment: Well, since you ask - start an SQL agent job. However, I don't want to give permission to user to start jobs (operations permission? something like that)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b672ee45-7198-4783-8143-2908f8a954d2/how-to-execute-sql-server-agent-job-from-trigger?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

Think you could do this from a trigger on the table;

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
ON TableName
AFTER INSERT
AS
   EXEC msdb..sp_start_job
        @job_name = 'JobName';
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, but as already mentioned earlier, this will not work unless the user has the "operations" permission

Comment: I see - you could use the trigger to execute a .bat file and have that file use the osql utility to call the agent job (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1730/different-ways-to-execute-a-sql-agent-job/)

Comment: Thanks, but seems overly complicated. Appreciate your comments, but doesn't answer the questions.